# With pure javascript: If one radio button is checked, then only display the next part

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I want to display the 2nd part of the form only once the user has selected a radio button in the first part. I'm trying to do this with javascript alone, but with no effet. I'm quite sure the problem lies in triggering the function at the right time. If I trigger it afterwards with a button, it works! But I want it to trigger automatically without needing an external button.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="entreprise_ou_particulier" value="Vous êtes un particulier" id="particulier1">
<label for="particulier1">
    <span>
        Je suis un particulier
    </span>
</label>
    
<div class="item" id="declaration2">
    <input type="radio" name="choix_de_produit" value="Déclaration d'impôts" id="declaration1">
    <label for="declaration1">
        <span>
            Déclaration d'impôts
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

and the Javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById("particulier1").checked) {
    document.getElementById("declaration2").style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("declaration2").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 5):

It’s an `<input>`, you can use the `change` event.

```
let check = document.getElementById("particulier1")

check.addEventListener("change", myFunction)

function myFunction (event) {
    if (this.checked) {
         document.getElementById("declaration2").style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
         document.getElementById("declaration2").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: `check.addEventListener("change", myFunction)` will only trigger if `#particulier1` is actively checked, not when it’s unchecked by another radio button. [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) like `addEventListener("change", ({target}) => { if(target.matches("input[type='radio'][name='entreprise_ou_particulier']")){ checkRadio(); } });` solves this problem, where `checkRadio` is a function that contains OP’s original code.

Comment: Ooh right, I was thinking of a checkbox, not a radio button, so sorry

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you!! It works flawlessly

I recognize my question was a duplicate of a previous question. Nonetheless, user4642212 did give an answer more complete than the answer in the previous duplicate.

user4642212's addition was [name='entreprise_ou_particulier']. By the way, I have a question about that: the point of this part of the code is to make me not run into any problems once my form is longer and includes several radio butons. Am I right?